# How do I run the same specflow tests in multiple browsers one at a time in .net Core?

Tags: c#, selenium, .net-core, specflow

I am using Specflow, Selenium, and .net Core.  I am trying to find a way to tell the test runner to run each of the tests in each of 3 browsers one at a time and am having no luck.

I see plenty of information out there for full .net framework.  And I see options when using SpecRunner, but I do not have access to either of these.
 Has anyone else figured out how to accomplish this?  Thank you for your help.

```
@Firefox
@Chrome
Scenario: Find Customer
    Given I am logged into site
    And I want to search for a Customer from the Quote screen
    When I type customer number XXXX into the text box
    Then Customer Stuff is available to be selected with customer number XXXX
```

```
       [BeforeScenario("Firefox", Order = 1)]
        public void BeforeScenarioFirefox()
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(".");
            driver.Manage().Window.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(-4000, 0);
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            initializePages(driver);
        }

        [BeforeScenario("Chrome", Order = 2)]
        public void BeforeScenarioChrome()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver(".");
            driver.Manage().Window.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(-4000, 0);
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            initializePages(driver);
        }
```

What is actually happening is that it is launching both browsers.

Comment: Have you a look at [this](https://specflow.org/2018/single-test-targeting-multiple-browsers/)

Comment: Yes, I did.  This is for people using SpecRunner which I do not have a license for.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5755/what-is-the-best-way-to-have-a-specflow-project-run-across-multiple-browsers) , may be you can do something like in 2nd answer in there

Answer (score 0):

I've created a SpecFlow plugin which will help in this scenario. It supports SpecFlow 2.4 and also SpecFlow 3+ (core). Documentation can be found here: https://github.com/totaltest/SpecFlow.Contrib.Variants

It supports NUnit, MsTest and xUnit. Essentially you can tag your scenarios in what I refer to them as variants, the scenario will then run for each variant.

e.g. The below scenario will run two times for each browser

```
@Browser:Chrome
@Browser:IE
Scenario: A scenario title
```

In terms of your case of 'running at one time' this comes down to parralelism and the solution for that will be more of an infrastructure solution I would say. Other factors would include limitations of SpecFlow itself - as I've read running scenarios (test methods) in parralel isn't well supported.

Hope the plugin is somewhat useful though.